# Отправка данных с формы на разные email, в зависимости от выбора select

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть форма, в ней есть несколько полей (телефон, страна, цель и выпадающий список с адресами).

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе разных адресов из выпадающего списка, форма отправляла данные на разные email. То есть к каждому адресу прикреплять определенный email.

Сейчас скрипт отправки выглядит так, и отправляет только на один указанный адрес в recepient.

```
<form id="form">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" 
placeholder="+7(___) ___-__-__" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Страна" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="target" placeholder="Цель" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<select name="adress">
<option>Выберите адрес</option>
<option>Адрес1</option>
<option>Адрес2</option>
<option>Адрес3</option>
<option>Адрес4</option>
<option>Адрес5</option>
<option>Адрес6</option>
</select>
</div>                                              
<button type="submit" class="btn slide-btn bg-inverse">Отправить</button>
</form>

<?php
    $recepient = "mail@gmail.com";
    $sitename = "Заявка";

    $phone  = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $country = trim($_POST["country"]);
    $target = trim($_POST["target"]);
    $adress = trim($_POST["adress"]);

    $message = "Телефон: $phone \nСтрана: $country \nЦель : $target \nАдрес: $adress";

    $pagetitle = "Название фирмы \"$sitename\"";
    mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; 
    charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `value` с адресами для `option` в `select`

```
<select name="adress">
    <option value="mail-1@gmail.com">Адрес1</option>
    <option value="mail-2@gmail.com">Адрес2</option>
    <option value="mail-3@gmail.com">Адрес3</option>
</select>

<?php
    switch($_POST['adress']){
        case 'mail-1@gmail.com':
            // сделать что то с mail-1@gmail.com, например:
            $recepient = "mail-1@gmail.com";
            $adress = "Адрес1";
        break;
        case 'mail-2@gmail.com':
            // Выбран 2
        break;
        case 'mail-3@gmail.com':
            // Выбран 3
        break;
        default:
            // Что то пошло не так
    }
?>
```

Comment: Супер! Благодарю!!!!

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
<select name="adress">
  <option value="">Выберите адрес</option>
  <option value="addres1@ya.ru">Адрес1</option>
  <option value="addres2@maiil.ru">Адрес2</option>
  ...
</select>

...
$adress = trim($_POST["adress"]);
if ($adres == '') {
  $recepient = "mail@gmail.com";
} else {
  $recepient = $adres;
}
```